# No Appearance --> Header menu

Tags: theme-development, logo

According to this page:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/

There should be a header page under appearance.  I added the theme support for custom logo but have got no header page under appearance.

The docs make it sound like this page exists and I don't have to add it myself.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress Version 4.1 removed this custom header screen and the link of Appearance > Header menu was directed to the Header Image section in the Theme Customizer.

Refer the [Customize Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Customize_Screen) for more detail information about Customizer.

*Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Header_Screen*